# How to specify optional JSON body from app script to IFTTT Maker channel?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ifttt

I am trying to send an IFTTT request through the Maker channel and want to send some extra data (status). Here's the code that I am using (in Google App Script):

```js
function postToMaker(url, status) {
  var payload = {
    "status": status
  };

  var payloadJson = JSON.stringify(payload);

  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'json',
    'payload': payloadJson
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

The code triggers IFTTT, but the variable "status" is not sent as extra data. I am sure there is something minor that I am missing. Appreciate all your advice.

Comment: Have you tried `'payload':payload`, instead of `'payload':payloadJson` and leave out stringify the payload?  Also, you can set the return from UrlFetchApp.fetch() equal to a variable, and then see what is returned into the variable.  `var whatWasReturned = UrlFetchApp.fetch();  Logger.log('whatWasReturned: ' + whatWasReturned);`

Comment: Still nothing...
When: February 6, 2016 at 12:39PM
Extra Data: , , ,
here is the log:  whatWasReturned: Congratulations! You've fired the test123 event

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help you, but you can view the headers with:  `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
   Logger.log(response.getAllHeaders().toSource());`  I don't know anything about IFTTT, so hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: Did the below answer help? If so could you mark it as answered. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Your payload is restricted to keys of "value1", "value2" and "value3" only.

> To trigger an Event Make a POST or GET web request to:
>
> [https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{event}/with/key/f_lWZAtMef6szM4PCoHSpSndFhd95dmQ3WkhX_qheOW](https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/%7Bevent%7D/with/key/f_lWZAtMef6szM4PCoHSpSndFhd95dmQ3WkhX_qheOW).
>
> With an optional JSON body of:
>
> { "value1" : "", "value2" : "", "value3" : "" }
>
> The data is completely optional, and you can also pass value1, value2,
>   and value3 as query parameters or form variables. This content will be
>   passed on to the Action in your Recipe.

Comment: I think this answers the question. The Maker channel does not seem to have a way to get all the data, only data with values as specified (Value1, Value2, Value3). If I try to use any other data from the payload, I get a message like "Unrecognized Ingredient: {{payload}}"